# Django - The view accounts.decorators.wrapper_function didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, python-decorators

I am building an customer management app and have built few decorator's. but when i run the app give this error

> **The view accounts.decorators.wrapper_function didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

decorators.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        elif request.user.is_authenticated == None:
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func


def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator


def admin_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

        if group == 'customer':
            return redirect('user-page')

        if group == 'admin':
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_function
```

and my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

from .models import *
from .forms import OrderForm, CreateUserForm, CustomerForm
from .filters import OrderFilter
from .decorators import unauthenticated_user, allowed_users, admin_only

# Create your views here.
@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user =form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')


            messages.success(request,'Account was created for '+ username)
            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/register.html',context)

@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password or incorrect')
    context = {}
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html',context)


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@admin_only
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    customers = Customer.objects.all()

    total_customer = customers.count()
    total_orders = orders.count()
    delivered = orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
    pending  = orders.filter(status='Pending').count()


    context = {'orders':orders,'customers':customers,'total_orders':total_orders,'delivered':delivered,'pending':pending}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def userPage(request):
    orders = request.user.customer.order_set.all()

    total_orders = orders.count()
    delivered = orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
    pending  = orders.filter(status='Pending').count()

    context = {'orders':orders,'total_orders':total_orders,'delivered':delivered,'pending':pending}
    return render(request, 'accounts/user.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def accountSettings(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/account_settings.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def product(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/products.html', {'products': products})

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def customer(request,pk_test):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk_test)

    orders = customer.order_set.all()
    order_count = orders.count()
    myFilter = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders)
    orders = myFilter.qs
    context = {'customer':customer,'orders':orders,'order_count':order_count,'myFilter':myFilter}

    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def createOrder(request,pk):
    OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer,Order, fields=('product', 'status'),extra=10)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    #form = OrderForm(initial={'customer':customer})
    formset = OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none(),instance=customer)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print('Printing POST',request.POST)
        #form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST,instance=customer)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/')



    context = {'formset':formset}
    return render(request,'accounts/order_form.html',context)


@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def updateOrder(request,pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = OrderForm(instance=order)
    context = {'form':form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print('Printing POST',request.POST)
        form = OrderForm(request.POST,instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request,'accounts/order_form.html',context)


@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def deleteOrder(request,pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order.delete()
        return redirect('/')
    context={'item':order}
    return render(request, 'accounts/delete.html',context)
```

[Output when i run my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l40hI.png)

**This is my first question tell me if i am not giving any information which is useful to answer this**

Comment: The wrapper function in admin_only does not return a response if the conditions are not met. You need to return something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lain Shelvington mentioned in comments, your `admin_only` decorator doesn't return a response for groups other the "admin" and "customer":

```
def admin_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

        if group == 'customer':
            return redirect('user-page')
        elif group == 'admin':
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return # <- return response here (possibly a redirect to login page?)

    return wrapper_function
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, how i solved it? actually it was a silly mistake.
First off all.
Go to admin, go to users than in group section,you will see that you have not assigned any group to that customer. assign customer group or admin group, according to your choice.

This was my mistake, i did not assign any group.  I hope you made same mistake there.

Comment: Thank you! It helps. Hail Dennis Ivy :)

Answer (score 2):

Shiv,

If you're following Dennis Ivy's tutorial and you're still having that problem, try the following:

1. Log in to the Django admin site with a superuser account
2. Go back to the main site
3. Log out and try to create another user

I got the same error when working through the signals video. I'm not sure if there is another bug that needs to be fixed, but this got the app working for me again.

Answer (score 2):

Shiv,

I am assuming that you are following Dennis Ivy's tutorial on youtube...

I had the exact same problem. And for me, it was because when I was first migrating my database from sqlite to PostgreSQL and then from PostgreSQL to AWS RDS, somehow all my user informations got lost.

My workaround to this was to create a new superuser (since mine got deleted) with:
`python manage.py createsuperuser` then with this new superuser login info, log into the admin panel. You will see that your superuser is **not** assigned to any groups yet, and if you check your Groups panel, you will see that the group variables we created earlier, namely `customer` and `admin` are not here. So go ahead and create those two group types. Then go back to the Users panel and assign your superuser the admin variable.

Then logout and go to your `/register/` page and create a normal account (not admin, just a customer). Then if you log into your superuser account and go to the admin panel again, you will see that your regular user (customer) is assigned with the `customer` variable just fine.

This is how I fixed the problem. I hope it helps you with yours. Cheers.

Comment: Had the same error. Thanks for the detailed clarification. 

Hail Dennis Ivy :)

Comment: Hii 
I have done the same but after I register a normal user and click on profile this error comes: "ValueError at /profile/ Required parameter name not set".

Answer (score 1):

for some people that will get this error, the response of user "sogu" fixed it in my case:
[SQLite works, but PostgreSQL migrated database causes ERROR - Django 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026338/sqlite-works-but-postgresql-migrated-database-causes-error-django-3-0/61129748#61129748)
(if the other solutions won't work out for you, just see that one)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the account that you are logging with does not belong to any group. I assume this is the admin account you first created. Go to admin page --> then to users --> and assign admin group to him. But a better answer was given up there, as it does provide a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to automatically assign the new user the group he'll belong to.

```
@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):

    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
            user.groups.add(group)

            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)

            return redirect('login')
        

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```